# Validation field setCustomValidity() method

Tags: javascript

I have to do the validation of the input text field.
I would like Js to show an error message through the setCustomValidity() method.
Is it possible?

```js
function checkName() {
  var x = document.formUser;
  var input = x.name.value;
  if (input.length < 3) {
    input.setCustomValidity('This field is invalidate');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="formUser" id="formUser" action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
  <div class="section">
    <label for="fname">Nome</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Invia" onclick="validateForm();">
</form>
```

Comment: Who is calling `checkName`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `reportValidity()` on the `input` after setting the custom validity message.

> Additionally you must call the `reportValidity` method on the same element or nothing will happen.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity#examples

```js
function checkName() {
  const inp = document.getElementById('name');
  const val = inp.value;
  if (val.length < 3) {
    inp.setCustomValidity('This field is invalidate');
    inp.reportValidity();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="formUser" id="formUser" action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkName();">
  <div class="section">
    <label for="fname">Nome</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Invia" onclick="checkName();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to control more text input with javascript.
The setCustomValidity() method means that it will have to show an error message if input has less than three characters.
it doesn't always work.
Eg. If I put a string of one character in the first field and a string of four in the second field; it sends without showing the error. If I repeat the same test, it works.
Why?

```
    window.onload = function() {
  const field = document.getElementsByClassName("input-field");
  for (let i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    field[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
      const val = field[i];
      if (val.length < 3) {
        field[i].setCustomValidity('Field is invalid');
      }
    })
  }
}
      <form name="formUser" id="formUser" action="#">
<div class="section">
  <label for="fname">First name</label>
  <input class="form-control input-field" type="text" id="fname" required>
  <label for="lname">Last name</label>
  <input class="form-control input-field" type="text" id="lname" required>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add a `<p class="error">...</p>` inside your section div.

Hide it with css (display: none) and when you get an error in your validation add a class to that

like "show" to show it (display: unset).

Answer (score -1):

You can do custom form validation using Javascript like this.
Here I have just added a div with a warning and alert box. You can do whatever you want.

It will alert a warning if you will click on submit when fields were empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
  let x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  let alertBox = document.getElementById("alert-box");
  // Here instead of checking (x == " "), you can use your custom validations
  if (x == "") {
 
    alertBox.innerHTML = `<p>Form input are empty</p>`;  // appends a div with warning
    alert("Name must be filled out");  // alert box
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Validation</h2>
<div id="alert-box"> </div>
<form name="myForm" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The downvote is for you not working with `setCustomValidity` at all, which is what OP asked for.